# Type-checking algorithms

Tags: algorithms, programming-languages, reference-request, type-checking

I am starting a personal bibliographic research on type-checking algorithms and want some tips. What are the most commonly used type-checking algorithms, strategies and general techniques?

I am particularly interested in complex type-checking algorithms that were implemented in widely known strongly static typed languages such as, for example, C++, Java 5+, Scala or others. I.E, type-checking algorithms that are not very simple due to the very simple typing of the underlying language (like Java 1.4 and below).

I am not per se interested in a specific language X, Y or Z. I am interested in type-checking algorithms regardless of the language that they target. If you provide a answer like "language L that you never heard about which is strongly typed and the typing is complex has a type-checking algorithm that does A, B and C by checking X and Y using the algorithm Z", or "the strategy X and Y used for Scala and a variant Z of A used for C# are cool because of the R, S and T features that works in that way", then the answers are nice.

Comment: Maybe you should edit this question to ask about type checking for one specific language. Open-ended, list-style questions are generally discouraged on SE (though this particular site doesn't have a policy regarding that yet). Also: <type-system-elitist>Java's type system isn't complex</type-system-elitist>.

Comment: @sepp2k I agree that the question is far too broad, and I've voted to close accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps the question could be rephrased to be more specific, but I don't think it should be closed.

Comment: @sepp2k: I know that it is a bit broad, but ended this way because I don't want to limit the usefulness of the answers. BTW, I did not understand what you want to say with "<type-system-elitist>Java's type system isn't complex</type-system-elitist>". Java's 1.4 and below type system in fact were simple, but whit generics in Java 5, it became a lot more complex.

Comment: I rephrased it. However it did not changed very much.

Comment: Asking for one particular language would make the question more unsuited for this site, imho. The question should maybe ask for general techniques.

Comment: This question is extremely broad, and makes a poor example exiting the private beta. Since you have apparently received a satisfactory answer, re-writing the question to better match the information you received would improve its focus without invalidating Dave's work. Please do this, and then flag for it to be re-opened.

Comment: Ok, I spent 10 minutes trying to rephrase it again and did not come with any useful variation. If somebody knows how to make it better, be welcome to edit it. BTW, I don't think it is that way broad as it asks fo something clear with a specific answer. I don't want to say "what is implemented for the XYZ language" because I am interested in the general concept and to get what is common between them, discounting the very simple ones, instead of getting what was done for a particular specific language.

Comment: Well, I edited it again anyway, but it still is not much different than before.

Comment: I don't see how your edit helps. It's still far too broad. All these languages have very different issues. By the way, we're discussing this question on Meta: http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97/is-it-normal-for-questions-to-be-closed-by-moderators-in-private-beta

Comment: @Victor A basic tool are [Attribute Grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_grammar). You will maybe not be able to do every wicked thing you can imagine with them, but they are a good starting point.

Comment: @Gilles: Is it better now?

Comment: @Victor Much better, now I know what you're after. Thank you. (And there goes the last reopen vote.)

Comment: For background, read [TAPL](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/). It's mostly focused on functional languages, but the basic concepts are important and will help you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most research does not actually publish the type checking algorithms for full blown programming languages. You will find some formalisations of a large part of the type systems for full programming languages, such as the work done by [Drossopoulou and Eisenbach for Java](http://pubs.doc.ic.ac.uk/JavaTypeSystemSoundTaPOS/) or [Nipkov et al's work on C++](http://pp.info.uni-karlsruhe.de/publication.php?id=wasserrab06oopsla). More often, though, you will only find the type systems for some core part of the language (Featherweight Java is one example) or for the core concepts of a language such as the [local type inference approach of scala](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=360204.360207).

In conferences such as POPL and ICFP you will find many type checking algorithms for specific kinds of type systems, and novel approaches such as [bidirectional](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/papers/strict/strict.pdf) and [tridirectional](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/papers/popl04.pdf) type checking.

More generally, you probably need to know about the [Damas-Milner algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_inference_algorithm), local type inference, bidirectional and tridirectional type checking, and expand from there, by following references in the papers and by using google scholar to find which papers cite these and build on the approaches described. Also, as suggested above, conferences such as POPL, ICPF, ESOP and even ECOOP and OOPSLA will have papers relevant to your quest.

Comment: Afaik, Scala's type system has been developed in research projects and is thusly published. The compiler is open-sourced, too. Have not looked into either, though.

Comment: No need for me to infer; I *know* that there are published papers on Scala's type system. This claim is readily checked by [searching](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=scala%20type%20system&btnG=Search&as_sdt=800000000001&as_sdtp=on). Also, I count the [compiler's source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/master/src/compiler/scala) as sufficient publication on the algorithm (provided it is included in the sources; I assume so but did not check). My initial statement was ambiguous, true, but your reaction seems unwarranted.

Answer (score 2):

A basic tool are [Attribute Grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_grammar). You will maybe not be able to do every wicked thing you can imagine with them, but they are a good starting point.

Essentially, you can walk over a program's abstract syntax tree top-down and/or bottom-up and pass information around. So, for instance, you could pass global scope type information (e.g. classes and their members) downwards and determine the type of expressions recursively, i.e. bottom-up, passing the resulting types upwards.

Find some explanation and examples in the slides [here](https://softech.cs.uni-kl.de/Homepage/CLP_SS09) (Chapter 5).

Comment: Does somebody have a better reference? I guess I need to buy the Dragonbook or Wilhelm/Maurer one of these days...

Comment: The tool [JastAdd](http://jastadd.org/) is an excellent, modern compiler compiler system based on reference attribute grammars. We've used it in a number of projects.